# Changing audio playback speed

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to change (increase/decrease) audio playback speed using Flutter?

Couldn't find any info about it and it seems like writing native code is the only option.

Comment: What are you using for the audio playback in your app?

Comment: The pitch-corrected algorithm is actually pretty simple if you wanted to port it. See https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/master/src/core/be/tarsos/dsp/WaveformSimilarityBasedOverlapAdd.java

Comment: @MiguelRuivo I'm using `audioplayers` package.

Answer (score 5):

The package [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) has incorporated support for playback rate:

```
_audioPlayer.setPlaybackRate(playbackRate: 1.0);
```

Comment: hey @syonip could you share some code on how to use it? I am not being able to use the method..

Answer (score 1):

The more complete example of using [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers):

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class Player {
   static play(String src, Function onComplete, {double playbackRate = 1.0}) async {
    try {
      final player = AudioPlayer();
      await player.setPlaybackRate(playbackRate);
      await player.play(AssetSource(src));
      player.onPlayerComplete.listen((_) {
        onComplete();
      });
    } catch (e, stack) {
      log(src);
      log(e.toString());
      log(stack.toString());
    }
  }  


}
```

Use like:

```
Player.play(pathToFile, () {}); //normal speed
Player.play(pathToFile, () {}, playbackRate: 0.7); //slowly
Player.play(pathToFile, () {}, playbackRate: 1.5); //quickly
```

Note that `setPlaybackRate` has no effect on the Windows app.
I did not try an emulator but on a real Android device and the web on Chrome works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try an [audioplayers_with_rate](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers_with_rate) fork of audioplayers. It worked great for me, but I couldn't find where its code is located (it links to audioplayers). The same functionality provides [this fork](https://github.com/catoldcui/audioplayers) or [this fork](https://github.com/Weststreet/audioplayers) of audioplayers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use inappwebview package that will enable you to customize any Voice player using HTML Code by Sending it like that :

initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
url: Uri.dataFromString(
generateVoicePlayerHTML(voiceUrl),
mimeType: 'text/html',
encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))),

and you will create your Html Code inside abstract class "GenerateVoicePlayerHTML" also have many Attributes to use it depend on platform

References: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview