# how use funtion rate in audio_service flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm creating an audio player and I already have most of its functionality; however, I need the function to speed up the audio playback. I cannot find that function in the package I'm using.

If anyone knows of any tutorial on how to use this function to speed up the audio speed, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing audio playback speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832197/changing-audio-playback-speed)

Comment: the package i'm using is audio_service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### audio_service 0.17 and earlier

In the UI:

```dart
await AudioService.setSpeed(1.8); // 1.8x speed
```

In your background task:

```dart
@override
Future<void> onSetSpeed(double speed) => _audioPlayer.setSpeed(speed);
```

These work just like `seekTo` and `onSeekTo` in the [project example](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service/example) (which you can use as a guide), except that the parameter represents the speed rather than the seek position.

##### audio_service 0.18 and later

In the UI:

```dart
await audioHandler.setSpeed(1.8); // 1.8x speed
```

In your audio handler:

```dart
@override
Future<void> setSpeed(double speed) => _audioPlayer.setSpeed(speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Sets the playback rate - call this after first calling play() or resume().
  ///
  /// iOS and macOS have limits between 0.5 and 2x
  /// Android SDK version should be 23 or higher.
  /// not sure if that's changed recently.
  Future<int> setPlaybackRate({double playbackRate = 1.0}) {
    return _invokeMethod('setPlaybackRate', {'playbackRate': playbackRate});
  }
```

you can try like this or not?

audioplayers: ^0.16.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).